# Xpages Email & Calendar open in browser

Tags: email, browser, calendar, xpages

I want to have an option to my application to open the email & calendar from a  tag.
I have added this code that I've found:

```
try {

var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDbDirectory("D:/IBM/Notes/Data/").openMailDatabase();
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = db.getAllDocuments();
requestScope.status = "Mail database " + db.getTitle() + " is " +
(db.getSize()/1024).toFixed() + "KB long and has " + dc.getCount() + " documents";

} catch(e) {
    requestScope.status = "Error opening mail database\n" + e.toString();
}
```

It's seem that something is wrong.

Thank you,

Florin

Answer (score 1):

The `getDbDirectory()` method expects a server name as parameter (and not a absolute path). So try this instead:

```
try {    
    var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDbDirectory("servername/organization").openMailDatabase();
    var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = db.getAllDocuments();
    requestScope.status = "Mail database " + db.getTitle() + " is " +
    (db.getSize()/1024).toFixed() + "KB long and has " + dc.getCount() + " documents";
} catch(e) {
    requestScope.status = "Error opening mail database\n" + e.toString();
}
```